# Compiler option make error warning after -Wall -Werror

Tags: c, gcc

`-Wall -Werror` are already set. 
I need to add some flag to make unused-s not error but warning. `-Wno-unused` discards warnings at all. I want to see warning and succeed compilation. How?

I tried: `-Werror=no-unused` but it does not work. GCC 9.

Comment: What is "unused-s"?

Comment: unused-s are unused-functions, unused-variables, and others

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [GCC manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html):

> `-Werror=`
>
> Make the specified warning into an error.  The specifier for a warning is appended; for example `-Werror=switch` turns the warnings controlled by `-Wswitch` into errors.  This switch takes a negative form, to be used to negate `-Werror` for specific warnings; for example `-Wno-error=switch` makes `-Wswitch` warnings not be errors, even when `-Werror` is in effect.

So the option you want to pass is `-Wno-error=unused`.